# Postgresql LEFT JOIN returns more results than expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a table called `product_simulations` which has columns

`product_id` and `data`
data here represents JSON B that has {'simulation_id':1'}

Then, I have simulation table that has columns
`simulation_id` and `simulation_name`

I simply want to grab simulation_id from product simulation, then perform left join so that I can also have simulation_name, my product_sim has about 2k records, where as my simulation_table has over 1m record, when I do left join, it returns over 200k record, instead of 2k. Is left join not what I am looking for here? I simply want to write a query where along all the columns from product_simulations, for those simulation_id, I also want to get simulation_name.

```
SELECT ps.*,
s.simulation_name*,
ps.data ->> 'simulation_id' as simulation_id
FROM pricing.product_simulations ps
LEFT JOIN simulation s on s.simulation_id = simulation_id
```

Comment: You cannot join by output column. Replace with according expression.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of what you mean? @Akina

Comment: `LEFT JOIN simulation s on s.simulation_id = ps.data->>'simulation_id'`

Comment: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. -- this is what I get.

Comment: If so then use explicit data type convertion.

Comment: It's useful to accompany the description with CREATE TABLE scripts, sample data as INSERT INTO, and desired output for shown source data.

Comment: Please do not deface your post. Edit to make your question clear. [mre] [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: This is a weird data model. So, there are about 2 million simulations, but only about 0.1% of these are item simulations? And you outer join the simulation table, because despite the table names, an item simulation may not even be a "simulation" and thus not be found in the simulation table? What the heck?

Comment: What is "expected"? You got what you should have expected given the documentation/manual & language definition. But we can't read your mind. [mre] [ask] [Help] PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please look at the formatted version of your post before publishing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a column alias in the `WHERE` clause, because `WHERE` is executed *before* the output columns are calculated.

Consequently, both `simulation_id`s in your join condition

```
ON s.simulation_id = simulation_id
```

refer to the column in `simulation`. The condition thus is the same as

```
ON s.simulation_id IS NOT NULL
```

which produces way more result rows than you want.

Use the expression instead of the alias in the join condition:

```
ON s.simulation_id = (ps.data ->> 'simulation_id')::bigint
```

(assuming that `simulation_id` is a `bigint`)

Let me remark that using JSON in this table design was a bad idea.